# Finding the closest possible $\Omega$, $\mathcal{O}$ - bound (or if possible $\Theta$) for the following functions

Tags: functions, asymptotics, computational-complexity, upper-lower-bounds

So I have three functions:

$f(n) = n^{2/12} + log^{2018}(n)$

$g(n) = n^{2+(-1)^n}$

$h(n) = n(1+(-1)^n)$

I think for $f$ it would be 
$f(n)$ $\in$ $\Theta(n^{2/12})$, because $n^{2/12}$ grows faster than $log^{2018}(n)$, so $log^{2018}(n)$ is a constant factor.

But what about g and h? Arent they both alternating between $\infty$ and $-\infty$. Are there even a $\Omega$, $\mathcal{O}$ or $\Theta$ - bounds for them?

---

Comment: but wouldnt that mean, that $g(n)$ is always as fast as $n^3$ (expect of a constant factor)? But $g(n)$ is faster than $n^3$ if n is odd. Shouldnt it be $g(n)$ $\in$ $\Omega(n^3)$ instead? Because its atleast as fast as $n^3$

Comment: Sorry i worked with big O. $g(n)=O(n^3)$. And $h(n)=O(n)$. For $\Theta$, it doesn't work for g and h.

Comment: Oh now I understand. I also made a mistake. I mixed up $\mathcal{O}$  and $\Omega$.

Comment: But my assumption for $f(n)$ $\in$ $\Theta(n^{2/12})$ righ isnt it?

Comment: Yes it is right for $f(n)$, as $f(n)/n^{2/12}$ tends to 1, we can take by example $k_1=1/2$ and $k_2=3/2$ in the definition.